# DevTools - Turn off Issues warning?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

OK, I know there are some issues on the page I'm working on. But I don't need that warning at every refresh. It takes so much space. How can I turn it off?

[image: DevTools Issues warning]

Comment: Seems like you've enabled the Issues panel experiment in devtools settings so simply disable it.

Comment: You're right. I wasn't aware that my Chrome was beta. Thanks.

Comment: This feature is no longer in beta. The problem persists and it's still annoying. Anyone know how to turn it off?

Comment: Yeah this "Make good web pages" virtue signalling has gone a bit too far now.